# Doorkeeper with variable token expiration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, token, doorkeeper

I'm using [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) on my app and now I need to set `access_token_expires_in` as variable depending user.

This value is stored directly on user model but I can't find any way to create a token with this variable. Here is a part of my tests (not functional)

```
require 'error'

Doorkeeper.configure do

  orm :active_record

  resource_owner_from_credentials do |routes|
    request.params[:user] = {:email => request.params[:username], :password => request.params[:password]}
    request.env["devise.allow_params_authentication"] = true

    user = User.where(email: params[:username]).first
    if user.nil? #|| !user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      false
    else
      access_token_expires_in user.access_token_duration
      user
    end
  end
end
```

I've this (completely normal) error :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `access_token_duration' for #<User:0x007fed1c062898>)
```

I could directly update `auth_access_token` with my custom value when it's already created but it's a bit dirty.

Does anyone know another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an easy thing (I didn't restart my server)

```
require 'error'

Doorkeeper.configure do |c|

  orm :active_record

  resource_owner_from_credentials do |routes|
    request.params[:user] = {:email => request.params[:username], :password => request.params[:password]}
    request.env["devise.allow_params_authentication"] = true

    user = User.where(email: params[:username]).first
    if user.nil? #|| !user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      false
    else
      c.access_token_expires_in user.access_token_duration
      user
    end
  end
end
```